# dplyr - Rename column [EMPTY] created by readr

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

When using `readr_0.1.1` to read in a .csv file with a missing field name, the name is automatically set to `[EMPTY]`:

```
library("readr")
library("dplyr")
df <- read_csv(",foo\n1,bar")

> names(df)
[1] "[EMPTY]" "foo"
```

I am trying to rename `"[EMPTY]"` using `dplyr_0.4.2` but I cannot find the right solution.

I have tried:

```
> rename(df, baz = [EMPTY])
Error: unexpected '[' in "rename(df, baz = ["

> rename_(df, "baz" = "[EMPTY]")
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:1: unexpected '['
1: [
    ^
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Did you mean missing column name?  I tried to replicate this with a missing column name and I get `NA` for that column name.  Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: The example above is meant to be ther reproducible example (first three code lines). Don't you get a data frame with the first column named "[EMPTY]"?

Comment: I meant the dataset you have.  I created some data , but couldn't get [EMPTY]

Comment: The dataset I have is stored in a .csv that I am reading in. The first row begins with a ",", that is, the first element of the first (header) row is missing.  The .csv has the same structure as the string in my example.

Comment: `rename(df, baz = \`[EMPTY]\`)` works for me

Comment: @jeremycg indeed, thanks! Can you formulate it as an answer? Also, please give an explanation of why the backtick version is the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
dplyr::rename(df, baz = `[EMPTY]`)
```

We are using backticks, rather than quotes as we are referring to a "non-standard variable name" eg:

```
df$`[EMPTY]`
```

From `?Quotes`

> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.)
>   and the underscore. They must not start with a digit nor underscore,
>   nor with a period followed by a digit. Reserved words are not valid
>   identifiers.
>
> The definition of a letter depends on the current locale, but only
>   ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used
>   directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided
>   they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and deparse
>   will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double
>   quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to
>   a name).